# Как преобразовать Uint8Array в WAV Data URL (для Sam TTS)

Tags: javascript, url, wav, text-to-speech, tts

В общем, мне нужна была самостоятельная TTS модель на JS, и я решил использовать Sam. Я нашёл данный репозиторий https://github.com/discordier/sam, и стал разбираться с документацией.

Я хотел бы получить WAV файл в виде Data URL, но такой прямой возможности у библиотеки нет. Но, несмотря на это, готовый WAV она скачивать может. Решение я так и не нашёл, так что хотел бы попросить вас помочь.

Могу предположить, что можно вывести встроенный в библиотеку 8bit wave buffer array (Uint8Array), чтобы уже его преобразовать в нужный формат. Я вообще не разбираюсь в типизированных массивах JS, так что обратился к GPT. Он предложил данное решение:

```
  function uint8ArrayToArrayBuffer(uint8Array) {
     var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(uint8Array.length);
     var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
     for (var i = 0; i < uint8Array.length; i++) {
        view[i] = uint8Array[i];
     }
     return buffer;
  }
  
  function arrayBufferToDataURL(arrayBuffer) {
     var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     return url;
  }
  
  const result = arrayBufferToDataURL(uint8ArrayToArrayBuffer(sam.buf8('Hello world')));
```

Но его проблема в том, что вместо классического URL, он создаёт бесполезный для меня Blob.

Буду рад любой помощи! Заранее спасибо.